# Is there a way for a Maven project to inherit report configurations from a pom dependency?

Tags: reporting, maven, checkstyle, pom.xml

I know that it's possible to configure the  section in a parent POM and have it apply to the sub-modules in a multi-module project.  However, I'd like to have a separate POM to reference as a dependency so I can have a reporting configuration I can "mix in" to various projects without having to replicate my reporting configuration across multiple projects.  (See "dependency POMs" here:  http://sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

For example, for my Widget project, I have a parent POM (widget-parent) with two sub-modules, widget-core and widget-web.  I'd like to have a separate POM, static-analysis, that widget-parent depends on.  static-analysis would have a  block that would define Checkstyle and FindBugs reporting.  When I build Widget, I would expect Checkstyle and FindBugs to be run on widget-core and widget-web.

If your solution only works in a particular version of Maven, let me know.  We haven't upgraded to 3.x yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Maven 3 the reporting element in the pom is gone and replaced by a configuration element for the site plugin. You can then use the usual pluginManagement to define a configuration that is used everywhere. I would suggest to upgrade to Maven 3 in general anyway and this gives you another good reason..

Update: The reporting element has been brought back and works again with latest versions of the site plugin.

Comment: So I would be able to add a pluginManagement section to my "dependency POM" and have it work the same way it does in the parent POM?

Comment: you could add it in the parent pom. Mixin type addition of poms will only come in Maven 3.1 ..

Comment: Sounds good.  I'm going to try something else as well.  I see that you can configure plugins based on a profile, so I'm hoping I can put a configuration in the parent pom that is part of a profile.  That way, projects that want the reports can enable them with a profile at build-time

Comment: to do that you add the configuration in the pluginMgt in the parent and then reference the plugin in a profile in the children..

Answer (score 1):

This supposedly works since Maven 3.5, which was released in spring of 2017; see [the related issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-516).

Configuration defined in plugins under `<build><pluginManagement>` will be used under `<reporting>` too now.

Refer to [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) for further info, if you don't know how plugin-management works in Maven.