# Share maven plugin configuration between build and reporting sections

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, pmd

I have a maven project where I use several plugins (pmd, checkstyle) in the build and in the reporting section of the `pom.xml`. The former for enforcing several constraints and the latter for the site report. These invocations of the plugins mostly share common `<configuration>` elements and so far the only solution I found is to copy the respective XML fragments. Is there any way to avoid this duplication?

Example `pom.xml` fragments:

```
<project ...>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.pmd.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${target.java.version}</targetJdk>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${project.basedir}/codecheck/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                    <failOnViolation>${failOnStyleError}</failOnViolation>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pmd-check</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
...
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.pmd.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>${target.java.version}</targetJdk>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${project.basedir}/codecheck/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
...
```

Comment: You should use `<pluginManagement>`....

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried that, but this didn't work, at least for the PMD plugin.

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: maven version is 3.3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for a Maven project to inherit report configurations from a pom dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466736/is-there-a-way-for-a-maven-project-to-inherit-report-configurations-from-a-pom-d)

Comment: This supposedly works since Maven 3.5, which was released in spring of 2017; see [the related issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-516).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid this duplication?

No.

Maven will not reuse the configuration settings of build/plugins or build/pluginManagement for the reporting plugin.

"*mvn site* [...] uses only the parameters defined in the `<configuration>` element of each reporting Plugin specified in the `<reporting>` element, i.e. *site* always ignores the parameters defined in the `<configuration>` element of each plugin specified in `<build>`."

(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Reporting_Plugins)

So, even with `<pluginManagement>` you will have to copy the XML fragments for the `<configuration>` section.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with `<pluginManagement>` defined as follows:

```
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${plugin.pmd.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <targetJdk>${target.java.version}</targetJdk>
            <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
            <failOnViolation>>${failOnStyleError}</failOnViolation>
            <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
            <rulesets>
              <ruleset>codecheck/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
            <excludeRoots>
              <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources</excludeRoot>
            </excludeRoots>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Then it is possible to use it in `<build>`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
          <goal>cpd-check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

and `<reporting>`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>pmd</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried that but this didn't work for reasons I could not find out.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you tried using it in fresh project with just this PMD config?

Comment: as @ufkub states, this does not work, which also makes sense if you remember that pluginManagement is in `<build>`, so it makes sense it is not "visible" to other parts of the pom that are not under `<build>` themselfs, which `<reporting>` isn't.

Comment: This supposedly works only since Maven 3.5, which was released in spring of 2017; see [the related issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-516).